# IoC/DI in world of .NET/Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I`am a professional .NET developer and i know a lot of places, where IoC and in particular DI can improve application architecture (modularity, different interfaces abstractions, design-time proxies, advanced unit-testing, etc).
I know a lot of different frameworks for building loose-couple application design, such as Prism, MEF, Castle, ets., and every one implement/support IoC(DI) principles.

But i also interested in Java development, and i want to know:
*is IoC/DI are popular in world of Java and if it so, i want to figure out the most used area of this concepts and the most popular frameworks which can provide best facilities of using it?*

Comment: Why you think Java and .Net differ in this case? They both are languages trying to achieve the same goals. To answer your question: Yes, it's popular in Java as well.

Comment: What happens when you google "java ioc"?

Comment: Is there a problem that you're trying to solve here, are do you just wish to participate in a discussion about IoC frameworks in Java? From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: yeah, DI invented in Java, .net copied it.

Comment: @irreputable: DI existed before .NET and even Java existed, so that makes it impossible for it to be 'invented in Java'.

Comment: @Steven it takes a lot of effort and makes a huge different to bring something mainstream. do you know for 10 years Java has been a laughing stock of the MS camp? time proved it's the right direction of programming language. of course, that has nothing to do with .Net. .Net was invented out of blue, no inspiration from Java whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework).  It's a lot bigger now, but it germinated around the core of a solid IoC container.